# Regex to match only two specific words, e.g. Yes or No

Tags: regex

My attempt is:

```
^Yes|^No|^$
```

but when I use this, words other than "Yes" and "No" are matched

How do I fix it?

I've been testing my regex using [this online regex tester](http://regex101.com/).

Comment: or you could just `select case ucase$($word): case "YES", "NO": XXXXX ...`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?:Yes|No)$
```

In VBScript, something like this:

```
Dim myRegExp, FoundMatch
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Pattern = "^(?:Yes|No)$"
FoundMatch = myRegExp.Test(SubjectString)
```

**What was the problem?**

You had an alternation with three options:

- `^Yes` matches `Yes` at the beginning of the string, but will also match `Yes` in `Yes, man...`
- `^No` matches `No` at the beginning of the string, but will also match `No` in `No way!`
- `^$` matches the empty string

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett Tak for the typo fix, JF! No means No... :)

Comment: Terrific, Konrad, thanks for letting me know. See you next time! :)

Answer (score 3):

Below regex would match yes or no only,

```
^(?:Yes\b|No\b)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eU6xD6)

Comment: Ha we're psychically-tuned, we came up with exactly the same regex. Awesome! :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett now it seems ok.